# PHP - html_entity_decode to entire array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I am fetching JSON data for use in my website and I need to echo it, like this:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("/lang/translator.php"); // uses preg_replace to remove whitespace/newlines from my actual json file and then echo's it
    $i18n = json_decode($json, true);

    if (htmlentities($_GET['lang'], ENT_QUOTES) == 'en')
    {
        $arr = 'i18n_en';
    }
    else if (htmlentities($_GET['lang'], ENT_QUOTES) == 'ru')
    {
        $arr = 'i18n_ru';
    }
?>
```

And I use it like this:

```
<?php echo $i18n[$arr]['string_key']; ?>
```

The `string_key` holds in its value either a English or a Russian translation of my site, depending in which JSON array it is.

**The problem:**

When I upload my JSON file which holds Cyrillic characters (Russian) this happens:

```
хорошо --> &#1093;&#1086;&#1088;&#1086;&#1096;&#1086;
```

Every single Cyrillic character gets converted to HTML entities. So I found out I could use `html_entity_decode()` to counter that but imagine how time-consuming it is to do this for **every** single `<?php echo $i18n[$arr]['string_key']; ?>` call I have in my code. Isn't there any way around that? I tried passing `$i18n` to `html_entity_decode()` but it expects a `string`, not an `array of strings`. Any ideas?

My JSON example:

```
{
    "i18n_en":
    {
        "key0": "value0",
        "key1": "value1"
    },
    "i18n_ru":
    {
        "key0": "value0",
        "key1": "value1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlentities` on the `$_GET` values? `htmlentities` should only be used when displaying a value in a page and you don't want it to be rendered as HTML.

Comment: I just find this a good practice to defend against hacker attacks... Maybe I'll remove the calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have set `$arr`, you could apply `html_entities_decode()` to every string in the specified language with a foreach loop.

Something like this:

```
if (htmlentities($_GET['lang'], ENT_QUOTES) == 'en')
{
    $arr = 'i18n_en';
}
else if (htmlentities($_GET['lang'], ENT_QUOTES) == 'ru')
{
    $arr = 'i18n_ru';
}

foreach ($i18n[$arr] as &$myString) {
    $myString = html_entity_decode($myString);
}
```

**Edit.** Two posible solutions to fix `Warning: Illegal string offset 'i18n_en'`.

1:

```
foreach ($i18n[$arr] as &$myString) {
    if(isset($myString)){
        $myString = html_entity_decode($myString);
    }
}
```

2. 

```
foreach ($i18n[$arr] as &$myString) {
    $myString = html_entity_decode($myString, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Or maybe, both combined. Let me know if this works please.

Comment: This works but how to `echo` the new string? I tried doing `echo $myString[$arr]['key'];` but I get `Warning: Illegal string offset 'i18n_en'`.

Comment: Hmm... is maybe some of those strings empty?

Comment: Yes, about 2~3 of the Russian strings are empty.

Comment: Ok, I have two ideas for that warning, let me put it in the answer to make it simple to read. Johny P.

Comment: If I try to call it like `$myString[$arr]['slang']`, it doesn't. And I don't know any other way of calling it. If I just call `echo $myString;` I get a totally random string from the JSON array.

Comment: Oh... but `$myString` is not like "a new copied array with entities corrected". It's just a temporal variable to modify your initial array. So you have to access it like: `$i18n[$arr]['slang']` or `$i18n[$arr]['key']` (or whichever key).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run `html_entity_decode()` on an Array of strings you can use `array_map`. Like this:

`$resultArray = array_map("html_entity_decode", $inputArray);`

Comment: I get this: `Warning: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...`

Comment: It's not `html_entities_decode` but `html_entity_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `array_map()` function to call a function over each item in an array. An example can be seen below.

```
$decodedArray = array_map("decode",$i18n);

function decode($toDecode) {
    return html_entity_decode($toDecode);
}
```